# Jmeter is unable to record the .net remoting calls called from windows forms application

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

We have a legacy application developed in .net windows forms and it uses .net remoting to get the data from database/server.So when I open the winform desktop application and try to record it using recording option in jmeter , then it does not identify it and fails to record any calls.Is is even possible to record such calls using jmeter or any other tool?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [Microsoft .NET Remoting: A Technical Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973857.aspx)

> **HTTP Channel**
>
> The HTTP channel transports messages to and from remote objects using the SOAP protocol. All messages are passed through the SOAP formatter, where the message is changed into XML and serialized, and the required SOAP headers are added to the stream. It is also possible to configure the HTTP Channel to use the binary formatter. The resulting data stream is then transported to the target URI using the HTTP protocol.
>
> **TCP Channel**
>
> The TCP channel uses a binary formatter to serialize all messages to a binary stream and transport the stream to the target URI using the TCP protocol. It is also possible to configure the TCP channel to the SOAP formatter.

JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) is capable of recording **only** HTTP or HTTPS traffic, if this is the case - you'll need to configure your application to use JMeter as a proxy. If your application doesn't have proxy settings - most probably it respects system-wide proxy settings. See [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter) guide for configuration and troubleshooting instructions.

If your application uses `TCP Channel` - you should be able to record it using a 3rd-party tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and replay with [TCP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler). Alternatively you can consider [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) tool which comes with [TCPProxy](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/tcpproxy.html) which theoretically should be able to capture requests on lower level.

Comment: Thanks for the response..I tried recording these .net remoting calls originated by desktop application(winforms), however it fails to record.I don't know how to use the Grinder tool to record these .net remoting calls. Is there any other tool or can we record these programatically somehow and replay them?